# i want to loop ng-options for 50 times how can i do it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

```
<select  ng-model="test" ng-init="test = '1'">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    ............................
    ............................
    ............................
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="49">49</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

I have tried something like this i need in this format:

```
<select 
ng-model="test" 
ng-options="1 as One"
ng-init="test = '1'"
range="50"
>
</select>
```

How can i make it like for loop in **angularjs** `ng-options`,
i want to loop ng-options for 50 times how can i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` or `ng-options` are not foreach loops. They take an array, not range for an input. So initialise an array in the controller and pass it there as a parameter:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    // use your favourite filling method
    $scope.array = Array(50).fill().map((e,i)=>i+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-init="test=1" ng-model="test" ng-options="x for x in array">
</select>
{{test}}

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without js.? i mean only from angular view

Comment: @Mrworldwide yes, replace `x for x in array` with `x for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,..........]`

Comment: on init its becoming empty can u pls tell how can i select it '1'

Comment: And for ES5 i tried this but not working where im doing wrong.`$scope.array = Array(50).fill().map(function((e,i)){return i+1;});`

Comment: @Mrworldwide depends if you filled your array with strings or numbers. Try `ng-init="test = 1"` OR change your array to have strings instead: `x for x in ['1','2','3',...]`

Comment: @Mrworldwide slight syntax error with parameters, change `function((e,i))` to `function(e,i)`, if you need a conversion to a vanilla javascript, try using [Babel.js](http://babeljs.io/) (_"try it online"_ version)

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below :

```
   <select  ng-model="test" ng-init="test = '1'">
        <option ng-repeat="number in getLoop()" ng-value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
    </select>
```

And in your Controller add the below:

```
$scope.loopSize= 5;
$scope.getLoop= function() {
    return new Array($scope.loopSize);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-repeat and pass in an array 1 to 50.

```
<option ng-repeat="i in myArray"></option>
```